# Enable proper relative path in cron

Tags: php, cron

I have 2 servers that are on completely separate OS' and configurations.  One properly accepts `require_once '../file.php';` and the other doesn't, because it's relative to where the cron is loading I guess.

How can I fix the 2nd location so that it's relative path is from the relative path of the file.  I need this to work in 3 different environments (local, beta, and live) so I don't want to write a bunch of code on this page, I'd prefer a configuration adjustment if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative path not working in cron PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969374/relative-path-not-working-in-cron-php-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__FILE__` will specify the full file path of the current script.

[`realpath()`](http://www.php.net/realpath) translates paths with relative components into absolute paths.

This should work:

```
require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../file.php"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Chane the working directory to the running file path. Just use

`chdir(dirname(__FILE__));`

include_once '../your_file_name.php'; //we can use relative path after changing directory

in the running file. Then you no need alter every relative path to absolute one in all pages. This works fine for me.