# Running PHP script with Crontab (Plesk / CentOS6)

Tags: php, cron, centos, plesk

As a customer in Plesk, I am attempting to run:

```
php -q /httpdocs/_external/export/test.php
```

From this tutorial: http://daipratt.co.uk/crontab-plesk-php/

I'm receiving the error

"php: command not found"

Is there something I need to enable from the main user or a different command I would need to use to run the script?

(also tried /bin/php with no luck, there is no php file in that dir)

"which php"
-/usr/bin/php
(when I use this dir I also get "no such file or dir" I guess since when I use / it's pulling from the customers root not the server root)

Comment: If you have `ssh`access do a `which php` to see where the binary is (usually `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: What does this give you: `find / | grep php`. It could also be `php5`.

Comment: Added "which php" path in description. Is there a way to get it if I can't access the root dir? Or a way to give this customer permissions from the root admin

Comment: @ldiqual - It listed a million files (/usr/local/psa/...), it is php 5.3...oh I gotcha the command, still no luck "php5: command not found"

Comment: php is installed, right?

Comment: Yup, the script itself works great running directly. My bin folder for that user though would be /bin/, but there is no php file inside (there is however bash,grep,mkdir...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118699/php-require-path-does-not-work-for-cron-job) will help you. My understanding is that Cron runs everything relative to itself, so you should always use absolute paths when running something from Cron.

Good luck, and happy holidays!