# Crontab - Run in directory

Tags: unix, directory, relative-path, cron

I would like to set a job to run daily in the root crontab. But I would like it to execute it from a particular directory so it can find all the files it needs, since the application has a bunch of relative paths.

Anyway, can I tell crontab to run from a particular directory?

Answer (score 472, accepted):

All jobs are executed by a shell, so start that shell snippet by a command to change the directory.

```
cd /path/to/directory && ./bin/myapp
```

Concerning the use of `&&` instead of `;`: normally it doesn't make a difference, but if the `cd` command fails (e.g. because the directory doesn't exist) with `&&` the application isn't executed, whereas with `;` it's executed (but **not in the intended directory**).

Comment: Rather than add a mostly duplicate answer, let me just add that you can choose which shell (if you need bash rather than sh, for example) by setting `SHELL` in your crontab.

Comment: So this command would be to execute the app (stored in bin) in another directory, wouldn't it? But if you already have the app installed in the right directory, the command I put in my answer would be ok, right? Sorry, I just wan't to understand the question.

Comment: +1. every other related question's solution is to re-write the script with absolute paths. this is exactly what I needed

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you use a semi-colon `;` instead of the double ampersands `&&` or would that not work? And why?

Comment: @JoshPinter Normally it doesn't make a difference. But if the `cd` command fails (e.g. because the directory doesn't exist), with `&&`, the application isn't executed. With `;`, it's executed (but not in the intended directory).

Comment: I will do this to all the cron jobs of my apps , you saved me from changing my source files, thank you very much

Comment: I get that this is almost 100X more upvoted than using the man page. But the answer is YES, you CAN  tell crontab to run in a certain directory when setting up your cronjob "in the root crontab." Just define its HOME.

Comment: @dlamblin You can't make a cron **job** to run in a different directory that way. Setting `HOME` has the incidental effect of starting **all** jobs in that directory, and is likely to cause the jobs to look for or drop files in unexpected places.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' if your limitation is using only one crontab file, you're right. But root level crontab has supported one file per job for decades. `"/etc/cron.d (and its siblings cron.daily/weekly/monthly) is preferred for all system crontabs. You shouldn't need to touch /etc/crontab."`

Answer (score 20):

Reading `man 5 crontab` should tell you that there's a `HOME` variable set which can be redefined in the file. It becomes your working directory. You can set `PATH` for the command(s) too. Of course this affects all the cron schedule lines.

E.G.

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8)
> daemon.  `SHELL` is set to `/bin/sh`, and `LOGNAME` and `HOME` are set from
> the `/etc/passwd` line of the crontab´s owner.  `HOME` and `SHELL` can be
> overridden by settings in the crontab; `LOGNAME` can not.
>
> (Note: the `LOGNAME` variable is sometimes called `USER` on `BSD` systems
> and is also automatically set).

Depending on your cron of course, but mine also has `MAILTO`, `MAILFROM` `CONTENT_TYPE`, `CRON_TZ`, `RANDOM_DELAY`, and `MLS_LEVEL`.

So for your hypothetical app I'd recommend a file name `/etc/cron.d/hypothetical` containing:

```sh
# Runs hypothetical app @ 00:01Z in its local path for reading its config or something.
SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/where/the/app/is
PATH=/where/the/app/is:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
CRON_TZ=UTC
1 0 * * * theappuser hypothetical --with arguments
```

For example with `docker-compose` relying on the cwd `docker-compose.yml`:

```sh
SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/path/to/composed-app
5 5 * * * root docker-compose restart -t 10 service-name
```