# Redirecting output does not work

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to output the most recent changelist number from our source control software to a log file. I know that the script works fine until getting the changelist number. The script below works when I run it manually but doesn't seem to work when it is triggered from the crontab. I have no idea why it wouldn't work. I am running this script on a machine with Mac OS X 10.7 and the permission are set to 555.

```
changelist=${changelist_ouput}

output_file="../../output_dir/result_log.txt"

if [[ -e ${output_file} ]];
then
    # Delete previous changelist information
    sed -i.bak '/changelist/d' "${output_file}"
    rm "${output_file}.bak"

    # Add current changelist information
    echo "changelist=${changelist}" >> "${output_file}"
else
    echo "WARNING: Failed to update changelist information"
fi
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` probably isn't using the same current directory as you are using. Since you use a relative path for `output_file`, this will dump the output to some path relative to `cron`'s current directory (and since `../../output_dir` probably doesn't exist, it'll just fail).

You have to use an absolute path for `output_dir`, or make a path relative to the script directory (`dirname $0`). See also [Crontab - Run in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899737/crontab-run-in-directory).

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks :)