# Cron Job Error when running a PHP file

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a php file via cron job, the file works fine when I run it manually, but when I run it in a cron job, I get this error:

```
Warning: include(classes/EmailAddressValidator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/onecent_dev/classes/MiscFunctions.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'classes/EmailAddressValidator.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/onecent_dev/classes/MiscFunctions.php on line 3
```

MiscFunctions.php & EmailAddressValidator.php are both existing files and are in the right place, what gives?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like your include_path is resolving . to whatever cron happens to have the current directory set to, as opposed to the directory where your script is. Try editing your crontab to cd first:

```
0 * * * * cd /path/to/script && php script.php
```

Or provide the include_path explicitly:

```
0 * * * * php -d include_path=/path/to/script script.php
```

Comment: Using the `include_path` method did not work for me. I got "Could not open input file: script.php"

The first option worked and seems simple enough. My question is, is there any con to `cd`ing in a Cron job? Cron gets its own shell and does whatever there, right?

Would this mean future jobs would technically be run in /path/to/script then? Where is Cron's default working directory then? Thanks

Comment: _"Would this mean future jobs would technically be run in /path/to/script then?"_ No, just this job. You could also do `php /path/to/script.php` without the cd first.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [PHP: Require path does not work for cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118699/php-require-path-does-not-work-for-cron-job)

Your include_path doesn't contain the path of the script you're executing.