# how to resolve fatal error from require in php to try to load files?

Tags: php, static, path

Workspace: php 5.4 on localhost and server (dreamhost shared)

In localhost the code works fine but on server no:
message error from server:

**Warning: require(/home/user/domain/view/../view/config/templateGlobal.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/domain/view/TemplateController.php on line 13
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/domain/view/../view/config/templateGlobal.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/user/domain/view/TemplateController.php on line 13**

the code from TemplateController.php

```
    class TemplateController {

            private static $paths = array();
            private static $pathsCssJs = array();
            private static $appInfo = array();      

            public function __construct(){
                self::$paths = require __DIR__.'/../config/paths.php';
                self::$pathsCssJs = require __DIR__.'/../view/config/cssJsPaths.php';
                self::$appInfo = require __DIR__.'/../view/config/templateGlobal.php';          
            }
}
```

the path for cssJsPaths is the same to templateGlobal.php, the name is correct, i just don't undertand whats happening.

if i remove `../view/` from the paths, on localhost works fine too, but on server the cssJsPaths.php and templateGlobal.php dont work

Comment: Check file permissions

Comment: file permission is ok

Comment: In the bold text, some paths have 'config' in them, some don't.    Is that verbatim out of the log?  Is 'config' a normal directory?

Comment: why are you going one folder up with /../ and then choose the same folder /view/ ?

Comment: yes, config is a directory, have one config in root that have paths.php, and have another directory view/config/ in this the problem start, one of the files have problems to be loaded just on server, at localhost is ok

Comment: @M.Svrcek, i just trying to understand what is going wrong, if i remove the ../view/ no archive can be loaded... but with it, just one load and the other no...

Comment: i dont know if the __construct() just accept one static var...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anfer many hours searching and reading i identify some problens: the comment from [M.Svrcek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667885/m-svrcek) make me think more about the paths, and this question [Require path does not work for cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118699/php-require-path-does-not-work-for-cron-job?rq=1),
i got the tip from [Robus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293316/robus), to identify where the php file work. I changed the paths to:

```
self::$pathsCssJs = require __DIR__.'/config/cssJsPaths.php';
self::$appInfo = require __DIR__.'/config/templateGlobal.php';
```

And the stupid part, i had 2 forlders 'configs' and 'config', just move the files to 'config' and delet the 'configs', now is working... thanks to everyone that tryied to help me. :) ... sometimes is too simple to belive that is wrong...