# Correct Cron job command in order for PHP require() to work

Tags: php, cron

I'm on GoDaddy shared hosting. In my cron job PHP script, I use **require()** to include some other files. The cron job PHP script works fine when I use it manually (via entering its url to the address bar), but when the cron job is performed, the cron script works fine, except it can't find the required files.

I have the following cron command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/domainname/cron/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118699/php-require-path-does-not-work-for-cron-job) that one option is to use full paths in **require()**. Another option is to modify the cron command, which is what I want to learn. My question is how to modify the above cron command so that my **require()** in the cron script will work (without using full paths).

Thanks.

Comment: `without using full paths` consider making a few constants for your path and including only that file.  `define('ROOT_PATH', '....')` etc...  You may also be able to simply use `__DIR__` if you are not using it.  So It may be helpful to see how you use `require` (tip. no parenthesis needed for it).  The only time I had an issue like this with `__DIR__` it was in either a symlink or a bind mount folder (can't remember).  But it wasn't PHP's fault (it's like a wormhole in your HD ... lol )

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks for your input. Using __DIR__ is a nice option, but still, I would like to learn how to write the correct cron command.

Comment: For C-Panel that is the correct way, for non-Cpanel  you just leave this bit off `/usr/local/bin/`  - That said I always use `__DIR__` so I never have these issues.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix But, as mentioned in my question, when I use the above command, it can't find the required files -files included in the cron script with require()-.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the easiest way to fix it.

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); //its been a while but I think __FILE__ works better with bind mounts and symlink but don't quote me on that.
//chdir(__DIR__);
```

I can't quite remember, but I think I had to use this one time for a wordpress site, that I made a cron job for. If I remember correctly it had some relative directories, from 3rd party plugins etc...

Other wise you can use `__DIR__` before your files.

I never use relative directories, I either use a constant

```
 define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__); //or something else besides __DIR__
```

Or I just use `__DIR__` and never have these kinds of issues. I like knowing exactly where my files are.

```
require __DIR__.'/somefile.php';
require BASE_DIR.'/somefile.php';
```

This is not really a PHP issue, its more an issue of how cron calls the PHP file, because the relative paths will be relative to the location of the crontab file.

**Summery**

That said about using `__DIR__` I know from my own experience, you can't control how third parties include files, so `chdir` is probably the only workable solution in that case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation about using __DIR__. My question about the correct cron command still holds.