# PHP include in a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to setup a PHP file as a cron job, where that PHP file includes other PHP files.

The file itself is located at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/protected/classes/cron/runner.php

The include file is at 
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/protected/config.php

How do I include that config file from runner.php? I tried doing require_once('../../config.php') but it said the file didn't exist.. I presume the cron runs PHP from a different location or something.

The cron job is the following..

/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/protected/classes/cron/runner.php

Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative path not working in cron PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969374/relative-path-not-working-in-cron-php-script)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your cron should change the working directory before running PHP:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/protected/classes/cron/ && /usr/bin/php -q runner.php
```

Note that if the directory does not exist, PHP will not run runner.php.

Comment: Perfect, did the trick nicely. Didn't realise you could run other commands from the cron line..

Comment: You could probably try to use an absolute path as well, rather than `../../conf` your could use `realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/conf`. Then your first approach should work.

Comment: Why call another function (realpath)? On PHP < 5.3, I would just use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/conf'`, and for PHP >= 5.3 `dirname(__DIR__).'/conf'`. But this change in the cronjob does not require a change in the PHP code itself, which could save you searching in your files for possible dependencies on the working dir.`

Answer (score 2):

You should use an absolute path.  The cron is probably not running the script from within the directory in which it resides.

I recommend using:

`require_once( dirname(__FILE__) '../../config.php )`

`__FILE__` is a special constant that refers to the file you're in.  `dirname(...)` will give you the directory, which will evaluate to the absolute path of the file you wish to include.

Comment: for PHP 5.3.0+ , `dirname(__FILE__)` can be replaced with `__DIR__` . Also , the above code missed a `.`

Answer (score 1):

Is classes or cron a symbolic link? I seem to remember that php evaluates the real path instead of the symbolic path.

Consider the following directory tree:

/target/index.php

/path/sym -> /target

if you were to execute `php index.php` from `/path/sym` then the statement `require_once('../require.php');` would evaluate to `require_once('/require.php');` not `require_once('/path/require.php');`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the working directory inside your PHP script to the location of that script:
`chdir(__DIR__);`
(or, if your PHP version is before 5.3: `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));`)
Then you can do:
`require_once('../../config.php')`