# PHP include_once works in local but call in cron not working

Tags: php, cron

I use include_once to include file in php it will works in localhost but same file run using cron it shows error

```
File name : cron_all.php
<?php
    define('project_name','/cloud');
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].project_name."/references/library.php");
?>
```

**error:**

> [root@xx-xxx-xx~]# php
>   /var/www/html/cloud/cloud_ip_automation/cron_all.php
>
> PHP Warning:  include_once(/cloud/references/library.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/cloud/cloud_ip_automation/cron_all.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once(/cloud/references/library.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/cloud/cloud_ip_automation/cron_all.php on line 3
>
> PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/cloud/references/library.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/cloud/cloud_ip_automation/cron_all.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/cloud/references/library.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/cloud/cloud_ip_automation/cron_all.php on line 3

Comment: You're searching in the wrong directory. Maybe `$_SERVER['document_root']` isn't pointing to where you think it's pointing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative path not working in cron PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969374/relative-path-not-working-in-cron-php-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $_SERVER variable is not set when running from CLI.
You have to use `dirname(__FILE__)` and make the paths relative to the current file.

For example in your case, something like:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'.project_name.'/references/library.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will create an absolute path, but relative to the file

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'.project_name.'/references/library.php';
```