# Is it possible to have cron job running on Amazon lightsail instance?

Tags: php, cron, amazon-lightsail

I would like to set up periodic jobs on an Amazon Lightsail instance, but I can find no information on it - only for Amazon EC2.

Is it possible to issue cron jobs on a lightsail instance, or do I need to change to EC2?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To answer my own question, just 8 hours later: **It IS possible to issue cron jobs on Amazon Lightsail instances**

Here is a working example of running a PHP script:

1. Connect to your Lightsail instance either by [logging in to your lightsail account](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com) and clicking "Connect using SSH" or using a SSH client, such as PuTTY.
2. Create a folder called 'projects' in /home/bitnami/ and create a simple .php file called Hello World:

   ```
   <?php print("Hello World"); ?>
   ```
3. Use command `crontab -e` to access a document, from where you can add lines that will be your scheduled cron jobs.
4. Append two lines to the document AND ADD A NEWLINE:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin:
   * * * * * php -f /home/bitnami/projects/HelloWorld.php > /home/bitnami/projects/Out.put
   ```

   **Line 1** adds php to the cron path (Cron sees a different path than what is given in the environment variables. Type: env and hit enter in the console). To see which env variables are given to cron replace line 2 with: `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` and look in the file. **Line 2** is the cron schedule. The asterisks means: Do this every minute of every hour, day, month, year. Search Google for this :) And will output to a file called `Out.put`.
5. Wait 1 minute and see that `Out.put` has been created and contains the magic words of **Hello World**

If you are having problems with cron jobs not working, check out this troubleshooting guide: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Hope this helps. If it does not, post a comment before downvoting!

Comment: Make sure you are using absolute paths if you are using include or require in your PHP file.  

This post explains CRON and relative paths:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969374/relative-path-not-working-in-cron-php-script

I couldn't get this answer to work and it was not the CRON setup, but my PHP file that was the problem.

Comment: how would this look on servers that do not run bitname but plain PHP? Also, what if the cronjob should open a site on another server? Can this be done?

Comment: Try running `which wp` and `which php` from the command line to see the path of your executables.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node.js, you can do this by adding a few lines to your crontab. First, open the crontab

```
crontab -e
```

Add these three lines at the end of the file. I'm assuming you are using forever.

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin:
@reboot cd /home/bitnami/**THISISYOURFOLDER** && /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/forever **NAMEOFYOURAPP.JS**
0 1 * * * sudo reboot
```

This will run your app that is in **THISISYOURFOLDER** when the system reboots. In addition, I'm setting it up to reboot at 1am everyday with this setting.

To test this, you can use

```
* * * * * cd /home/bitnami/**THISISYOURFOLDER** && touch myfile.txt
```

in your crontab. This needs to create myfile.txt in your target folder after a minute. If it doesn't you need to change your path setting. There is also a difference between

```
sudo crontab -e
crontab -e
```

Find time settings at https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a node package for cron if you're using node?